# Turing Machine with non trivial states and transitions

Tags: turing-machines, computation-theory, computation

Please give me some idea as to how to go about this

Draw a Turing machine (using Sipser notation) having at least 4 nontrivial (i.e., nonrejecting) states and at least six nontrivial (i.e., not to the rejecting state) transitions.

Answer (score 2):

A Turing machine has:

- A finite number of *states*, of which one is *accepting* and one is *rejecting*. The task apparently requires five states (four nonrejecting (of which one must be accepting) and one rejecting). The states are usually drawn as circles, with a label (the state name) inside each. One of the states is the *starting state*; it is marked with an arrow pointing at it.
- A finite *input alphabet*. {0, 1} or {a, b} are typical choices.
- A finite *tape alphabet*, which includes a special *blank symbol*, all symbols from the input alphabet, and possibly more symbols (but this is not required).
- A *transition function* which assigns a state, a tape symbol and a *direction* to each combination of a state and a tape symbol. The direction can be L (left) or R (right). A transition is drawn as an arrow from one state to another (or possibly a circular arrow from a state back to itself), and the arrow is labelled with two tape symbols and either L or R. Apparently, you need six such arrows.

The machine also has an infinite *tape* that is divided into cells. In each cell, there can be a symbol from the tape alphabet. The symbols that initially are on the tape are called the *input* to the machine. The machine has a *read head* that is always located over one of the cells. Let's say you have a transition arrow from state A to state B, with the symbols a, b, and R on it. That means: "If the machine is in state A and the symbol under the tape head is a, then we should replace that symbol with b, go to state B, and move the read head one cell to the right."

Comment: (In case it's the formulations "nontrivial states" and "nontrivial transitions" that baffle you, they just mean "a regular state that is not rejecting" and "a regular transition between regular states". There is nothing special about the "nontrivial" states or transitions - the point is just that you're not supposed to make a machine with where all states are rejecting or one where all transitions go to a rejecting state.)